# xbmc / kodi what ports to open on firewall so I can see files via upnp

Tags: firewall, xbmc, dlna, upnp, kodi

I'm running xbmc / kodi 14.0 on my ubuntu 14.04 machine and I'm trying to view / watch my files located on my Kodi ubuntu machine from my nexus 7 tablet.  I'm using bubbleupnp onmy tablet which can see my plex server but it can't see my kodi server are there ports I need to open up like I did for the plex server?  If so what are they?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I had to do.

1) Do a netstat to find the PID of kodi.bin on the Local Kodi server

```
sudo netstat -lp --inet
```

2) Then get the pid and do a grep on it, this will tell you the udp and tcp ports it uses.

```
sudo netstat -lp --inet | grep "$7609/"
```

[Link to example of it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/179733/how-to-do-a-netstat-that-will-only-filter-based-on-pid)

Comment: This can be done in one step via `sudo netstat --listening --program --inet --numeric | grep kodi`